# Filtering the line with the largest value for a given ID

Tags: python

I have a tabular file in which the first column has IDs and the second one has numeric values. I need to generate a file that contains only the line with the largest score for each ID.

So, I want to take this:

```
ES.001      2.33
ES.001      1.39
ES.001    119.55
ES.001     14.55
ES.073      0.35
ES.073     17.95
ES.140      1.14
ES.140     53.88
ES.140     18.28
ES.178    150.27
```

And generate this:

```
ES.001    119.55
ES.073     17.95
ES.140     53.88
ES.178    150.27
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: I've written a script that reads a line and makes a vector out of if. Then it stores the value of the value of the second column into a variable. It reads the lines until a different value is found in the first column. For each line read, if the value of the second column is largest than the one stored in the variable, the largest value replaces the previous. The problem was that my script skipped the first lines of each ID. I do not have the code right now, but I can post it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That a look in the code bellow. Maybe it can help you.

```
with open('FILENAME') as f:
      lines = f.readlines()
      ids = {}
      for line in lines:
            line = line.rstrip()
            line = line.split(' ')
            value = ids.get(line[0], list())
            value.append(float(line[-1]))
            ids[line[0]] = value

max_values = []
for key, value in ids.items():
      print key, max(value)
```